# Using autocomplete with LINQ query with an alias

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, autocomplete

I'm using autocomplete with a LINQ query.  The code works when I don't use an alias for the column but gets an error when I use an alias. Here is the code that works:

```
var suggestions = from v in db.ValueDocument
                          select v.HeaderTitle;

var namelist = suggestions.Where(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower()));

return this.Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If I change the query to below it gets an error.

```
var suggestions = from v in db.ValueDocument
                           select new { Header = v.HeaderTitle };
```

The error I'm getting has to do with the AnonymousType.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ doesn't have an object model for your aliased suggestions.

I would create a model for this aliased ValueDocument:

```
public class ValueDocumentAlias
{
     public string Header {get;set;}
}
```

Then modify your code to look like this:

```
var suggestions = from v in db.ValueDocument
                  select new ValueDocumentAlias{ Header=v.HeaderTitle };

var namelist = suggestions.Where(n => n.Header.ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower()));

return this.Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```